# Will the play store icon made by Image Asset in Android Studio cause "Hi-res icon" error?

Tags: android-studio, google-play

I use Image Asset in Android Studio to generate the Google Play store icon, you can see Image A.

It's 512 x 512, 32-bit PNG.

But Google Play reject it, the following information is displayed

*We found an issue in the following area(s): Hi-res icon*

Are there some bugs with Image Asset to generate the Google Play store icon?

**Image A**

[image]

**Reject Details**

[image]

Comment: Do they give more details about which exact policy it is breaking? It would also be good to know what the app does. Currently, I can guess that Google Play dislikes the icon as it is just the android microphone icon (which is commonly used in the android system, and may be misleading to users), and have not got a more original icon. I can guess it might either come under Impersonation (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9888374) or Misrepresentation (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9888689)

Comment: Thanks! would you please see my added content?

Answer (score 1):

Your app is rejected due to the policy here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9888374

Most likely this is the policy that it breaks:

> App titles and icons that are so similar to those of existing products or services that users may be misled

Google is probably worried that the icon is just an microphone icon, which is used in other places in the Android system, and may therefore mislead users that the app is related to Android or Google.

Therefore, I suggest modifying your icon to differentiate it and make it unique, and then they should accept it.